# How to iterate List<Map<String,Object>> in java

Tags: java, collections

I have one List which contain one map i want to iterate is

```
List<Map<String, Object>> featureService=featureSubscriptionDao.getUnsubscribedSevice();
```

my dao method is

```
@Override
public List<Map<String, Object>> getUnsubscribedSevice() {
    String sql="select * from tblservice where public='false'";
    return getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
}
```

any help ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
List<Map<String, Object>> featureServices = getUnsubscribedSevice();

for (Map<String, Object> featureService : featureServices) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : featureService.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: As opposed to corgraths solution, note how this one uses entryset instead of keyset to get the keys and values. This is better because one doesn't have to use get on the map (using the keys) to get the values (saving some time)

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can simply use a lambda function.

```
    featureService.forEach(service -> 
                service.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v)
   ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract from the lists of the map:-

```
for (Map<String, Object> objectMap : cal.getMap_formula()) {
                        objectMap.keySet();//method 1st
                        objectMap.containsKey("key_name");//method 2nd
                        objectMap.get("key_name");//method 3rd
                    }
```